# Security issue (memory-dump) with connecting to database via ConnectionString .NET

Tags: .net, database, passwords, connection-string, memory-dump

I've getting across some security problems with using connectionstrings in .net oracle database providers which contains passwords.
Problem is that those providers (System.Data.OracleClient or ODAC) are getting connectionString in a parameter of String type.

It means that when we have desktop application connecting directly to a database (without some mid-layer service) and we do a memory dump for this application the most likely we get user and password in plain-text from the connectionString passed to database provider library.

As far as I know there isn't a way to pass the connectionString in SecureString type parameter (google says that only MS SqlServer provider allow this).

Is there any other way to secure database passwords in this case (except changing system architecture and creating mid-tier service for connecting to database instead of connect direct from applications) ?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's SqlConnection will, by default, remove the password from the **`.ConnectionString`** for you once you connect:

```
connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=screwdriver;User ID=MrSnrub;Password=smithers;";
connection.Open();

>connection.ConnectionString
"Data Source=screwdriver;User ID=MrSnrub;Password=smithers;"
```

You can override this behavior by specifying **Persist Security Info=true;**:

```
String cs = "Data Source=screwdriver;User ID=MrSnrub;Password=smithers;Persist Security Info=true";
conn.ConnectionString = cs;
conn.Open();

>conn.ConnectionString   
"Data Source=screwdriver;User ID=MrSnrub;Password=smithers;Persist Security Info=true"
```

### Use SecureString

The alternative is to use .NET 4.5's method to pass a password to an **SqlConnection** as a **SecureString** through an **SqlCredential** object:

```
SecureString pwd = AzureKeyVault.GetSettingSecure("DbPassword");
SqlCredential cred = new SqlCredential("MrSnrub", pwd);

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=screwdriver;";
conn.Credential = cred;
```